# Set Pug(Python) syntax in sublime with emmet

Tags: syntax, pug, sublimetext3, emmet

I want to set Emmet for Pug(Python) syntax in Sublime. It works ok with Pug, but when I select Pug(Python) it doesn`t work. 
Whet I set Pug it work fully. On Pug(Python) it work partionally:
! + tab works
ul>li*5 works
But link tab doesnt work, img tab dont work. When I click link and Ctrl+E its look like html selected. 
I read many simular themes, read emmet help.
[That is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEmIO.png)
Trying to set somethink like that in:

```
{
    "snippets": {
        "pug": {
            "filters": "jade"
        }
    }
}
```

But doest work. Please help.

Have some progression with that way https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet to add

```
{
  "operand": "source.pypug", 
  "operator": "equal", 
  "match_all": true, 
  "key": "selector"
},
```

Now its work on double tab click, but its HTML syntax for source.pypug scope.

Comment: Now after reading many manuals I have new knowledge.
I need to set PUG abbreviations for source.pypug scop.

Comment: New more complex info:
I am using Pug(Python) syntax highlighting in Sublime. By clicking ctrl+alt+shift+P it show that scop:
source.pypug tag.pug complete_tag.pug entity.name.tag.pug
Its work ok with Pug syntax highlighting and that scope:
    text.pug meta.tag.other entity.name.tag.pug
By this manual https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet I set tab for my scope in sublime-keymap User, by this:
    "context": [ { "operand": "source.pypug", "operator": "equal", "match_all": true, 
    "key": "selector" },

Comment: Now I have that situation: by clicking tab its work partition. !+tab do right pug syntax, img+tab ok but link+tab not, abbr trasform to:
<link rel="stylesheet" href=""> and I need to click double tab to get abbr to syntax.

Think that problem is that:

1.Emmet see Pug(Python) source.pypug like HTML it some cases. So I want to understand where to set full suppourt of Pug abbr, for Pug(Python) like it works with text.pug.

Comment: 2.I need double click tab in some situations. Maybe some conflict in config is.
3.And sometimes I got HTML abbr transform, sometime PUG, its not stable.
Please write me how to fix it, how to set full Pug abbr for source.pypug. Emmet see Pug(Python) source.pypug like HTML it some cases. So I want to understand where to set full suppourt of Pug abbr, for Pug(Python) like it works with text.pug.

Comment: Emmet 2 solved this problem: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/578

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is asked poorly but these will help: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages.
"[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"
"[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
"[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
"[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". Don't use comments to modify your question. Ask a question, get an answer, then create a new question. As is this will be closed.